# Properties of normalizer of (Sylow $p$-subgroup of the stablizer of a point)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

(The original is a proof exercise but apparently contain print errors so I had to edit it to make sense, thus I'm not sure about its validity, which greatly hindered my attempt)

Exercise 2.4.13: Let $G$ be a permutation group on $\Sigma$, fix arbitary $a\in\Sigma$, let $H=\mathrm{Stab}_G(a)=\{g\in G\mid ga=a\}$, $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$, $\Delta=\{b|b\in Ga, Pb=b\}$ is points fixed by $P$ in orbit $Ga$, does $N_G(P)$ necessarily acts transitively on $\Delta$?

Attempt to solve:

Result from Exercise 2.4.12 says when $G$ is a permutation group on $\Sigma$, $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, $a\in\Sigma$, if $p^m\mid |Ga|$ then $p^m\mid |Pa|$. In this result replace $G$ with $H$, $a$ with $b$, then $Pb=b\Leftrightarrow|Pb|=1\Rightarrow p\nmid|Hb|$, and because $|Pb|\mid|P|=p^k, P\leq H$ so $p\nmid|Hb|\Rightarrow |Pb|=1$. Thus $b\in\Delta \Leftrightarrow p\nmid|Hb|$.

Beyond that my efforts were fruitless.

Comment: @Derek Holt when $G=H$, $Ga=a$, but $\Delta$ is a subset of $Ga$. a point b belongs to $\Delta$ if it is fixed by $P$ AND b is in $Ga$. Or to say, only points in $Ga$ is considered rather than the full $\Sigma$, and $G$ acts transitively on $Ga$. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. The answer is yes, $N_G(P)$ acts transitively on $\Delta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sketch proof that $N_G(P)$ acts transitively on $\Delta$. Let $b \in \Delta$. Then there exists $g \in G$ with $ga=b$.

Note that $P$ and $gPg^{-1}$ are both Sylow $p$-subgroups of ${\rm Stab}_G(b)$, so there exists $h \in {\rm Stab}_G(b)$ with $hgP(hg)^{-1} = P$. Then $hg \in N_G(P)$ with $hga=b$.

Comment: Thank you! The remaining detail is $P$ is in both $Stab_G(a)$ and $Stab_G(b)$，the latter two being conjugate, so $P$ is Sylow $p$-subgroup of $Stab_G(a)\Rightarrow P$ is Sylow $p$-subgroup of $Stab_G(b)$.